# Why is there have a line ? I didn't add that line

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Why my app have a line for each cardview ? even though I didn't add it.
In design preview, I not see that line. And when app run, that line appear.

[image: my app sreenshot]

I am using recycler view to make this view.
Below my users_item.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/userAvatar"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:src="@color/silver"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_regular"
            android:text="@string/username"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userAvatar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/userAvatar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/location"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/userAvatar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userName" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_chevron_right_24"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Below my activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:queryBackground="@null"
    app:queryHint="Search User"
    app:showDividers="end" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/search"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/search"
    tools:listitem="@layout/users_item" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Any help, I'm very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have dividers on between elements in your RecyclerView?

Comment: Do not post screenshots of your code or xml.  Use cut and paste to include them in the question as text.  (And then format them.)

Comment: done, i edit it. please check it again :)))

Answer (score 1):

This is a default divider of RecyclerView

if you want to remove it, so only put single line in your adding after recyclerview iinitialisation

recycle.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context, 0));